# How to perform online Swagger Editor validation in a command-line tool?

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I am using the online Swagger Editor (https://editor.swagger.io/) to validate my swagger, and it is giving me helpful error messages such as:

```
Semantic error at paths./whatever/something...required.3
Read only properties cannot be marked as required by a schema.

Semantic error at definitions.whatever.properties.whatever.description
Sibling values are not allowed alongside $refs
```

I need to perform this validation with a command-line tool, as part of a build.  I can't find anything in any swagger.io project that will do this.  In addition, I have tried the following third-party tools, all of which claim that my Swagger is valid:

- swagger-cli
- swagger-tools
- swagger-codegen-cli

Is it possible to get the validation offered by the online Swagger Editor, but in a command-line tool?

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [Swagger 2.0 offline validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978671/swagger-2-0-offline-validation)

Comment: Also I guess related - a GitHub issue
https://github.com/APIDevTools/swagger-cli/issues/57