# Swagger definition file validation in Java

Tags: java, api, swagger, openapi

Short version: I want to validate a JSON model to see if it is a valid swagger model.

For example, I have:

```
{
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "version" : "0.0.1",
    "title" : "API"
  },
  "basePath" : "/api",
  "paths" : {
    "/{myVar}" : {
      "get" : {
        "summary" : "Summary",
        "parameters" : [],
        "responses" : {
          "200" : {
            "description" : "OK"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I use the online editor (editor.swagger.io), I have the following error:

> Semantic error at paths./{myVar} Declared path parameter "myVar" needs
>   to be defined as a path parameter at either the path or operation
>   level

I would like to retrieve the same error in my java code.

I tried the following:

- validating the json against the swagger schema (http://swagger.io/v2/schema.json)
- parsing the json with SwaggerParser.readWithInfo then calling getMessages (= empty list)

Any idea if it is feasible with the current java librairies?

Comment: I am using the simple [swagger core](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) packeage to validate them, it notice those missing parameters while parsing.

Comment: @Nathan thanks but I fail to see what class I could use in this module. Any example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger 2.0 offline validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978671/swagger-2-0-offline-validation) and [Validating JSON against Swagger API schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39275947/113116)